# Set password for certain events on Windows 7

Tags: windows, power-management, password-protection

Is it possible to configure Windows to ask me for the password after specific events?  Like, only prompting for my password after Hibernation or Shut Down, but never after Restart or Suspend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be not a safe route, but you are asking to do so, and this will allow you to bypass some of the build in safeguards.

In Start Menu, choose "Run..", then type *netplwiz* there, and in the window that pops up, select your user, and uncheck "users must enter a name and password..."

For suspend, go to Control Panel, power/energy options, and then click on advanced settings for the power saving schema you are using, and in the advanced settings window that pops, set "no" in the setting that says require password after suspend.

Comment: Why do you say it might not be a safe route? Can I damage my computer? Or just let other people to do so?

Comment: Well, is just a warning I always give when someone reduces the security on his/her computer. Not being afraid of you damaging your computer, but well, having the login barrier is always good for security. I know quite some people that had always this setting so with no harm.

Comment: Well thanks. One answer in a whole day, might as well select you and +1.